# How do I read an XML file (from different directory say from destop) in Angular 7?

Tags: xml, angular, file-upload

I am setting up XML import functionality. In this we have to upload the XML file from any location, say desktop, convert XML data to JSON (which is done by `xml2json`). But the problem rise during the file upload. The Code is given below

**LutCrud.html**

```
 <div  div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end" mat-dialog-content *ngIf="isUpload">
            <input mat-raised-button matTooltip="XML Import" class="LutButtons" type='file' accept='text/xml' (change)='openFile($event)'>            
          </div>
```

**LutCrud.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  fileToUpload: any;
  http: HttpClient;
    xmlItems: any;

// ----------------------------------------------------
  openFile(event) {
    this.fileToUpload = event.target.files[0];
    this.postFile(this.fileToUpload).subscribe(data => {
      // do something, if upload success
      console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }


  postFile(fileToUpload: File): any {
console.log(fileToUpload.name);
this.http.get(+'./' + fileToUpload.name
  , { headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
    .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method'),  
    responseType: 'text'
})
.subscribe((data) => {
  this.parseXML(data).then((data1) => {
      this.xmlItems = data1;
    });
});


}

parseXML(data) {
 // Here
  let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
       let xml = '<root>Hello xml2js!</root>';
       parseString(xml, function (err, result){
         console.dir(result);
});}

}
```

The respective error is shown in below image.

[image]

I think, there is error in line `this.http.get(+'./' + fileToUpload.name`. If there is any error or any better method please help me.

The MRC is given below link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8e88a

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Is the code you've shown supposed to be a *component*?

Comment: Yes that's a component. I will redit the Component.

Comment: MRC is provided... @jonrsharpe

Comment: **In the question.** What you've posted here doesn't make sense.

Comment: i have done haif of the xml to json. But dont know how to take xml values from xml file(which is not readable). I little bit changed the folder structure in the Reproduced example(LUT.component.ts as hello.component.ts (which handle the html code too)).

Comment: Your component isn't written correctly to have the HttpClient injected by DI. I'd recommend running through https://angular.io/tutorial, which includes how to get things injected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200543/discussion-between-sarath-mohandas-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much search, corrected the above code and published. So I can summarize the code.
**LUT.html(sample)**

```
<div  div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end" mat-dialog-content >
            <input mat-raised-button matTooltip="XML Import" class="LutButtons" type='file' accept='text/xml' (change)='openFile($event)'>            
          </div>
```

**LUT.ts**

```
 openFile(event) {

  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
        reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        var parser = new DOMParser(),
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(reader.result as string, 'text/xml');

        if (xmlDoc.documentElement) {           
            this.parseXML(xmlDoc.documentElement.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
        } else {
          console.log('NO DATA');
        }
        }
      }

    }

  parseXML(data) {
    // Here
    var result;
    var parseString = require('xml2js');
         let xml = data;
         parseString.Parser().parseString(xml, (err, r) => {
           result = r;
           console.log(result);
           this.xmlData = result;
       });
  this.importedData.emit(this.xmlData);
  if (this.xmlData != null) {
    this.isUpload = false;
  }
```